# What's the purpose of this diode in this level-shifter?

Tags: diodes, level-shifting, logic-level

look at this circuit:

[image: figure1]

I don't get that what's the usage/purpose of the BAS316 in this circuit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One purpose for that diode is to block a leakage current path if the +3VRUN rail is powered up but that the +5VRUN rail is not powered up. Allowing an unpowered rail to get leakage current from other powered circuits can lead to operational problems and potentially result in severe latch-up in circuits referenced to that rail when they become powered.

Comment: This must be the answer that I'm searching for! thanks.